# Showing a message if user already liked something

Tags: php, mysql

In my web application I have 2 buttons: one  is "like", the other one is "dislike".

Users can't like their own profile.

I am looking for now a bit of code so that if a database check shows there is already a row for the user who wants to like or dislike that profile a message comes up: "You have already liked this user" or "You have already disliked this user"

```
<? if ($_POST['like']){
  if(strtolower($view) == strtolower($fetchAccount['UserName'])){
    echo "You cannot Like yourself!<br /><br/>";
  } else {
     mysql_query("INSERT INTO `ProfileLikes` (`id`, `Profile`, `Rated`,
         `LikedDisliked`, `Date`) VALUES ('', '{$fetchUser['UserName']}',
         '{$fetchAccount['UserName']}', 'Liked', '$time')");
    echo "You Liked {$fetchUser['UserName']}!<br /><br />";
  }
}

if ($_POST['Dislike']){
  if(strtolower($view) == strtolower($fetchAccount['UserName'])){
    echo "You cannot DisLike yourself!<br /><br />";
  } else {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `ProfileLikes` (`id`, `Profile`, `Rated`,
      `LikedDisliked`, `Date`) VALUES ('', '{$fetchUser['UserName']}',
      '{$fetchAccount['UserName']}', 'Disliked', '$time')"); 
    echo "You DisLiked {$fetchUser['UserName']}!<br /><br />";
  }
}
?>
```

Can anyone help please? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: so what is wrong with to code you have already written to achieve this?

Comment: The code there is to insert to db when liked or disliked and also for users to not be able to like or dislike their own profile I need another bit of code so script checks database, if finds a row for user and user profile already liked or disliked want it to display a message

Comment: so you want us to write it for you? how about giving it a go first.

Comment: So you're saying you need a `(Select count(*) where id="$usrId") == 1` do an update command else do an insert. Like Dragon said, you have to give it a go first, we don't write it for you.

Comment: what is fetchUser and fetchaccount ? thez are from database ?

Comment: I read this as "... if user already *killed* something"

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Yes fetchUser and FetchAccount is with database thats how I have written to make them not be able to like/dislike themselves I have been trying different ways but can't get it so if someone has already liked or disliked the user it shows a message saying they have already done so and does not update the dadabase.

Comment: " have been trying different ways but can't get it" - show us your best/last effort.

Comment: Done thanks anyway people. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
<?php

//-------Like section---------
if ($_POST['like']){

  if(strtolower($view) == strtolower($fetchAccount['UserName'])){

    echo "You cannot Like yourself!<br /><br/>";

  } else {

     //Check whether user 'liked' the other user already.
     $selectQuery = "select * from `ProfileLikes` where `Profile` = '" . 
          $fetchUser['UserName'] ."' AND `Rated` = '" . 
          $fetchAccount['UserName'] . "' AND `LikedDisliked` = 'Liked' ";
     $resultSetCheck = mysql_query($selectQuery);
     $rowLikedExistsArray = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultSetCheck);

     if (!empty($rowLikedExistsArray)) {

         //He 'liked' it already!
         echo "You have already liked this user! <br /><br/>";

     } else {         

         //insert new 'like'
         mysql_query("INSERT INTO `ProfileLikes` (`id`, `Profile`, `Rated`,
             `LikedDisliked`, `Date`) VALUES ('', '{$fetchUser['UserName']}',
             '{$fetchAccount['UserName']}', 'Liked', '$time')");
        echo "You Liked {$fetchUser['UserName']}!<br /><br />";

     }
  }
}

//-------Dislike section---------
if ($_POST['Dislike']){

  if(strtolower($view) == strtolower($fetchAccount['UserName'])){

    echo "You cannot DisLike yourself!<br /><br />";

  } else {

     //Check whether user 'disliked' the other user already.
     $selectQuery = "select * from `ProfileLikes` where `Profile` = '" . 
          $fetchUser['UserName'] ."' AND `Rated` = '" . 
          $fetchAccount['UserName'] . "' AND `LikedDisliked` = 'Disliked' ";
     $resultSetCheck = mysql_query($selectQuery);
     $rowDislikedExistsArray = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultSetCheck);

    if (!empty($rowDislikedExistsArray)) {

         //He 'disliked' it already!
         echo "You have already disliked this user! <br /><br/>";

    } else {
        //insert new dislike
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `ProfileLikes` (`id`, `Profile`, `Rated`,
          `LikedDisliked`, `Date`) VALUES ('', '{$fetchUser['UserName']}',
          '{$fetchAccount['UserName']}', 'Disliked', '$time')"); 
        echo "You DisLiked {$fetchUser['UserName']}!<br /><br />";
    }

  }
}

?>
```

Note: I can see some optimizations to make. But dont wanna break your code flow.

Comment: I already done it I did post it up thanks anyway but this could still help others they would just need to edit it.